# insert data to table pivot use form and show it index.blade.php in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have form create team.blade.php below this

[image: form.blade.php]

Form Team index.blade.php

[image: index.blade.php]

[image: dd]

display the name of the one-team user with that user, and display the project that is being done by the user, and display the user as what (role).

the relationship of one user has many teams. and one team has many users. therefore, I choose many to many relations. but when I create team, I want to insert user_id and team_id in the pivot user_teams table as the relation table between user and team.

but when I tried to create team failed, he did not save data to the user_teams table.
and in the team index, he does not display the name of a team user with that user, and displays the project that is being done by the user, and displays the user as what.

**my user models**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Presence;
use App\Models\Project;
use App\Productivity;
use App\Sick_leave;
use App\Annual_leave;
use App\Models\Team;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'role_id',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
    }

public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'user_teams');
    }

public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::Class, 'user_projects');
    }
    }
```

**Team Models**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\User;
use App\Role;
use Auth;

class Team extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

protected $table = 'teams';
protected $fillable = [
    'id', 
    'project_id',  
];

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_teams');
}

public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

}
```

**Project Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Project extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $table = 'projects';
protected $fillable = [
    'project_id',
    'project_name',
    'start_date',
    'end_date',
    'project_category',
];

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_projects');
}

public function team()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Team::class);
}
}
```

**UserTeam model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class UserTeam extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;    
protected $table = "user_teams";

public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

**Team Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = auth()->user()->name;
    $users = User::all();
    return view ('teams.index', compact ('teams', 'users', 'projects'));
}
public function create()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $projects = Project::pluck('project_name', 'id');
    return view ('teams.form', compact('projects', 'users'));
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $team = Team::create($request->all());
    $userIds = User::find(2);
    $team->users()->attach($userIds);
    return redirect()->route('team.create');
}
```

In user_teams has fields `user_id` and `team_id`. how do i overcome this??

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the team and then attach the users that belong to it.

**Example from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):**

**Attaching**

> Eloquent also provides a few additional helper methods to make working
>   with related models more convenient. For example, let's imagine a user
>   can have many roles and a role can have many users. To attach a role
>   to a user by inserting a record in the intermediate table that joins
>   the models, use the attach method:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

**In your case:**

**Team Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $team = Team::create($request->except('user_id'));
    $team->users()->attach($request->get('user_id', []));
    return redirect()->route('team.create');
}
```

Comment: Do you have to add `user_id` in the table team?

Comment: No your schema is correct, Laravel will create the pivot with the `team_id ` and `user_id` for you, you only have to pass the `id` of the users to the attach method.

Comment: when I tried it, he entered the pivot table, but for `user_id` he did not match the `user_id` selected according to the selected option.

Comment: You have to pass the `users` that you select in your create form to the store action, at the moment your only attaching the user with the `id` of 2.

Comment: in `store` function. sorry

Comment: for select `user_id`, it should to save in table team.?

Comment: same at last. the `user_id` not same with select option

Comment: Are you passing the user_id to the store action?

Comment: No, in my field team, nothing `user_id`

Comment: Please add the output of `dd($request->all());` to your question.

Comment: its been add in my question. in my field team doesn't have user_id